# define the date attribute

Tags: mysql

In my `MySql` database I have a `date` attribute not `timestamp`, but I do not know how to write the Structure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the mysql documentation regarding date formats:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/datetime.html

> The DATE type is used for values with a date part but no time part. MySQL retrieves and displays DATE values in 'YYYY-MM-DD' format. The supported range is '1000-01-01' to '9999-12-31'.

Your default value 0000-00-00 is not in the supported range!